# Regex exclude characters from date/time

Tags: regex

I'm trying to convert the date/time from a message into another format but I lost track after matching the date and time.

Here's what I have:

```
<21>1 2014-06-06T14:32:50.010791+02:00 message etc
```

Here's how I cut the date and time:

```
(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)T(\d+):(\d+):(\d+).(\d+)+
```

Which produces:

```
2014-06-06T14:32:50.010791
```

Here's what I would like:

```
2014-06-06 14:32:50.010
```

Comment: What language/regex implementation are you using? Your attempted solution suggests that you need to learn more about regex. There are many resources on the web: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: what are you doing this in?

Comment: Try: `(\d+-\d+-\d+)T(\d+:\d+:\d+\.\d{3})` and use capture groups 1 and 2

Answer (score 1):

Just use \d{3} instead of (\d+)+

```
(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)T(\d+):(\d+):(\d+).\d{3}
```

or

```
\d+-\d+-\d+T\d+:\d+:\d+.\d{3}
```

P.S.

- To replace "T", you can use .replace("T", " ") or a similar method.
- As an alternative you can group (...)T(...) and then use group[0]+" "+group[1]
- It makes sense to use . instead of .

Comment: You can simply use .replace("T", " ")

Comment: Try: `(\d+-\d+-\d+)T(\d+:\d+:\d+\.\d{3})` and use capture groups 1 and 2

Comment: @JonM `^` is not necessary.

Comment: @smimov You need to escape the `.` character like so: `\.`